# Number of solutions to a+b+c<=n

Tags: c++, algorithm, math

everybody, this is in reference to this problem :[http://www.spoj.pl/problems/DCEPC702](http://www.spoj.pl/problems/DCEPC702/)/.(Kindly see there for a sample input).  I translated the problem statement to this finding the number of solutions to an equation of  this form `na + nb + nc <= newN` 
   `newN = N - (mina + minb + minc)` ,

`0<=na<=maxa - mina, 0<=nb<=maxb-minb, 0<=nc<=maxc-minc`.

I have then tried inclusion-exclusion to find the number of solutions. I am new to this principle, hence I am not sure if i am doing this right. My answer is incorrect anyways. Could someone tell me where I am wrong in this approach? Here is my code.

Thanks in advance.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cstdio> 
using namespace std;
#define MOD 1000000007

#define ulli  long long int

ulli f(int a)
{
if(a<0) return 0;
else
{
    ulli n = (ulli)a;
    return ((((n+3)*(n+2)*(n+1))/6))%MOD;
}
}


 int N;

 int minA, maxA;
 int minB, maxB;
 int minC, maxC;

  int main()
 {
   int T;

scanf("%d",&T);

while(T--)
{
    scanf("%d",&N);

    scanf("%d %d",&minA , &maxA);
    scanf("%d %d",&minB , &maxB);
    scanf("%d %d",&minC , &maxC);

    maxA -= minA;
    maxB -= minB;
    maxC -= minC;

    int A = maxA;
    int B = maxB;
    int C = maxC;

    N -= (minA + minB + minC);


    ulli res = f(N) -f(N-A-1)-f(N-B-1)-f(N-C-1)+f(N-A-B-2)+f(N-C-B-2)+f(N-A-C-2)-f(N-A-B-C-3);

    cout<<res%MOD<<endl;
}


return 0;
 }
```

Comment: I think you should add to the question "All constraints are up to 10^9. TL is 1s for 1000 test cases"

Answer (score 1):

You should probably work through some simple cases to see where you're going wrong.

One obvious problem: your formula for f is (N+3) choose 3; it should be (N+2) choose 2.  (If you have N total, you add 2 separators, and pick the location of those two.)

Some of the rest of your code is unclear, but correct.  I would do something like:

```
int A = maxA - minA;
```

rather than

```
maxA -= minA;
int A = maxA;
```

Also, there are potentially overflow errors, depending on how big the numbers are - multiplying all three numbers then dividing by 6 may overflow before you get to the mod.  What you should be able to do is figure out which of the three is divisible by 3, and divide that out, then figure which one(s) is/are divisible by 2, and divide out one factor.  Multiply two of the results, mod it, then multiply the final result and mod it.

Oh, and mod your final answer too, I think is what the problem asks for.